# Java3D: Very poor performance in applet on MacOS X

Tags: macos, java-3d

I'm trying to do some animations using Java3D on a Mac.

If I use `universe = new SimpleUniverse();` to create a universe, everything is fast.  The problem is that there's a bit of tearing sometimes because I'm altering object properties while in the middle of rendering.  What I would like to do is stop the rendering while I'm updating properties.

My first step was to try creating my own `Canvas3D`, and that's where things went wrong.  Rather than just creating a `SimpleUniverse`, I do this sort of thing:

```
GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
canvas = new Canvas3D(config);
universe = SimpleUniverse(canvas);
```

When I do this, the first problem is that the window doesn't automatically appear.  So based on the example at [java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/3D/Java3DandtheUserInterface.htm), I embedded the Canvas3D in an applet.  Then I get a window, but performance is TERRIBLE.  The rendering is MUCH slower.

It's almost as though the rendering is no longer being done by the graphics engine but instead in software.

Can anyone give me some tips as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should try compiling your BranchGroups before they become live. This helps preprocess the objects before they get displayed in the universe. It might also be something else that java is getting hung up on, if you put the whole source in the question, then i could tell you more. It might also just be your computer, Java3D takes a big hunk of Memory and is pretty CPU intensive, your computer specs would also be relevant in answering this question

Hope that helped you out a little bit, if you add more to your question i would be happy to help you more